# Table headers in the wrong direction

Tags: php, html, html-table

I'm currently trying to populate home HTML tables with some arrays in PHP, my HTML knowledge is far from sufficient and I was wondering if someone could help me with getting the table headers to go horizontally rather than vertically?

PHP:

```
print "<table>";
print "<tr>";
    for ($x=0; $x <=10; $x++)
    {
        print "</tr>";
        print "<th>$keys[$x]</th>";
        print "<td>$step[$x]</td>";
    }
```

OUTCOME:

These are the headers that I want to be displayed horizontally rather than vertically..

Any help appreciated as always, thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a row with headers, after that a row with the values.

```
print "<table>";
print "<tr>";
    for ($x=0; $x <=10; $x++)
    {
        print "<th>$keys[$x]</th>";
    }
print "</tr>";
print "<tr>";
    for ($x=0; $x <=10; $x++)
    {
        print "<td>$step[$x]</td>";
    }
print "</tr>";
```

Comment: Thankyou Bert! Appreciate that a lot!

Comment: Depending on how much value rows he would like to have (more than one) he would need to modify that a little bit. But in that case the perfect answer.

Comment: @KJaeg yeah - my next task is to get it to print all the values in the array rather than just one..

Answer (score 0):

```html
try this:    
print "<table>";    
print "<tr>";    
    for ($x=0; $x <=10; $x++)   
        print "<th>$keys[$x]</th>";
print "</tr><tr>";  
 for ($x=0; $x <=10; $x++)
        print "<td>$step[$x]</td>";
print"</tr></table>";
```